AWS ECS Task does not write new logs to CloudWatch log group
I have 5 days log retention period for a CloudWatch group so after 5 days logs are gone...
I have an ECS Task with logsConfiguration in definition, writing logs to this group, but because log-stream is deleted, task does not continue to write logs to the log group, so I can not see/find any logs.
I have also actions defined in task policy for log resource.
Is this normal? How can I be sure that logs are written?
*BTW, if there is a new task deployment a new log-stream is created and then logs are fine.

According to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managedservices/latest/userguide/log-customize-retention.html "The CloudWatch Logs log retention feature deletes the log events in a stream based on retention policy. It doesn't delete log streams or log groups." So the log stream and group are not deleted. What you are seeing is not how CloudWatch Logs retention is supposed to behave. It sounds like you may be encountering some other problem not related to the log retention period.

Thanks a lot @MarkB. Doing some other investigations according to your guidance...
But also if log stream is deleted manually, the active task does not create any other logs...I was expecting that ECS Task will continue to create logs within new stream, but no...So, is this default behavior?

If the log stream is deleted I would expect it to create a new log stream, as long as the task execution role actually has permission to create log streams, but I've never tested deleting a log stream like that, while an ECS task is running.
